# Pass an object attribute as Parameter java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dao

Can I pass an attribute as parameter in a method from my Repository?

Example:

```
@Query("select a from Account a where :attr = :value")
public Page<Account> searchByFilter(@Param("attr") 
       String attribute,@Param("value")String value,Pageable pageable);
```

Call example :

```
searchByFilter("status","Active",....);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Basically your query can be compiled and successfully executed, however it will be translated not the way you like.

At the end you'll have sql like this

```
select a.* from account a where 'status' = 'Active';
```

Note: status is translated to string value, not the column name.